# "Split bamboo" for different purposes

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

We split **bamboo poles** into two and sometimes more to make a variety of things.

Does *English* like my *native language* have specific *words and phrases* for split bamboo poles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your native language, what are the words you refer to, and what do they mean in English?

Comment: As some Japanese friends point out, English doesn't even have a word for "Bamboo" (as there are several quite different plants (in Japanese *take*, *sasa* etc) that are all just called "bamboo" in English.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thin piece of wood, metal, plastic or bamboo is called a *slat*.  If you split a large bamboo pole into flat pieces you could call each one a "bamboo slat".  This term is used by several bamboo wholesalers on alibaba.

> The fence was made by weaving bamboo slats between bamboo stakes that had been driven into the ground.

There is no specific term for a half-round bamboo pole. But a "half-round" would describe the shape clearly enough.

Answer (score 4):

Each country has a rich vocabulary for things that people deal with regularly. In England, we have very varied weather, so we have many different words to describe wet weather: mist, fog, cloud, drizzle, rain, hail, sleet, slush, snow, etc.

Bamboo is not native to England, and so we don't have any special terms for it.  We do, however, have many specialised terms for ways to process the types of wood native to England. For example, one traditional method of making a barrier round a field in England is [hedge laying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgelaying), and terms like pleacher, stake, brash and crook are used to describe different ways of using the wood in the construction of the hedge.

Comment: One thing also confuses me: do you prefer to say "bamboo poles" or "bamboo stems"?

Comment: @user100323: according to this ngram graph  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bamboo+pole%2C+bamboo+stem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbamboo%20pole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbamboo%20stem%3B%2Cc0 , bamboo pole is more widely used but, as other forms of bamboo are not common in England, we generally just use the word 'bamboo' to refer to bamboo poles.